# Finding Distinct Sublists with Target Sums

Tags: python, algorithm, math, permutation, sublist

I am currently working on a task that involves identifying distinct sublists from a given list such that each sublist adds up to one of the specified target numbers.

Below is the Python code I've written to address this problem. The primary approach in this recursive function involves iteratively removing elements from the list and assigning them to a sublist corresponding to one of the target numbers or discarding them. The function terminates either when a solution is found and outputs the result or when it's unable to complete due to an empty list or overshooting in one of the sublists.

```
def subset_sums(numbers, target_array, total_partial=None, partial_sum=None):
    # If it's the first function call, initialize partial_sum and enumerate numbers to detect duplicates
    if partial_sum is None:
        numbers = [(v, i) for i, v in enumerate(numbers)]
        total_partial = [[] for _ in range(len(target_array))]
        partial_sum = np.zeros(len(target_array))

    # If all sublists have the correct sum, yield the resulting sublists
    if (target_array == partial_sum).all():
        yield total_partial
        return

    # If we don't reach a correct result and have no numbers left, stop the function
    elif not numbers:
        return

    # Get the next number and the remaining list
    n_with_index = numbers[0]
    n = n_with_index[0]
    remaining = numbers[1:]

    # Case 1: Skip the new number and continue with the rest of the numbers
    yield from subset_sums(remaining, target_array, total_partial, partial_sum)

    # Case 2: Use the new number for each possible list
    for j in range(len(target_array)):
        # If using the new number would overshoot in that list, stop
        if (partial_sum[j] + n) > target_array[j]:
            return
        # Otherwise, use the new number and continue with the rest of the numbers
        else:
            next_total_partial = total_partial
            next_total_partial[j] = next_total_partial[j] + [n_with_index]
            next_partial_sum = partial_sum
            next_partial_sum[j] = next_partial_sum[j] + n
            yield from subset_sums(remaining, target_array, next_total_partial, next_partial_sum)
```

However, I've encountered a persistent flaw in the code that I can't seem to resolve. The problem lies in the fact that the same list element gets appended to different sublists, and the algorithm fails to exclude list elements as expected. I've thoroughly reviewed the code, but I can't pinpoint why this issue persists.

The following snippet shows an example instance:

```
In [1]: list(subset_sums2([1,3,1,3], np.array([3,5])))
Out[1]: []
```

However, I expect the output:

```
Out[1]: [
    [[(3, 1)], [(1, 0), (1, 2), (3, 3)]], # target 3 is the 3 at index 1; target 5 is the sum of all other numbers 
    [[(3, 3)], [(1, 0), (1, 2), (3, 1)]]] # target 3 is the 3 at index 3; target 5 is the sum of all other numbers
```

Note that the output is (value, index) pairs. Here we have two ways of getting the target numbers of 3 & 5: They're identical except for which given 3 is used to achieve the 3 target vs the 5 target.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance that could help me identify and rectify the problem in my implementation. Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: An example of input and expected output would be helpful

Comment: notice that you have a recursion call which refers to a different implementation! `yield from subset_sums2(...`

Comment: @cards Thanks for pointing that out. I've added a short example and corrected a typo in the recursive function's call arised during code cleaning.

Comment: Are we guaranteed that the sum of the given list is equal to the sum of the target list, so that the only question is to enumerate all the ways we can combine indices of the given list to generate the target list?

Comment: Finding a subset of given numbers that match just one target number  is the NP-hard subset sum problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: @Dave No, this is not guaranteed. The indices of the resulting sublists must be distinct but do not have to form a partition in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this section:

```
    for j in range(len(target_array)):
        # If using the new number would overshoot in that list, stop
        if (partial_sum[j] + n) > target_array[j]:
            return
        # Otherwise, use the new number and continue with the rest of the numbers
        else:
            next_total_partial = total_partial
            next_total_partial[j] = next_total_partial[j] + [n_with_index]
            next_partial_sum = partial_sum
            next_partial_sum[j] = next_partial_sum[j] + n
            yield from subset_sums(remaining, target_array, next_total_partial, next_partial_sum)
```

When your function is called with the example you provided:

```
list(subset_sums([1,3,1,3], np.array([3,5])))
```

Even on the second iteration there's already a problem. On the first iteration, `next_total_partial` is set to `total_partial`, and then `next_total_partial` is updated on the next line. But this modifies both `total_partial` and `next_total_partial`, as they have the same value.

So, on the second iteration, you think you reset `next_total_partial` with:

```
            next_total_partial = total_partial
```

But in fact, nothing changes - it still has the same object as a value and you now add the same value (`(3, 3)` in this case) to both `next_total_partial` and `total_partial`.

Perhaps you wanted `next_total_partial = total_partial.copy()`? The same applies to `next_partial_sum = partial_sum.copy()` of course.

It would be possible to fix your logic to get it to work, but it's not a very efficient approach and it has a few other problems:

- the main issue is what I pointed out: you pass around the same objects where you need copies
- you have a recursive function, but you also use it for initialisation - this would be better with a secondary outer function, or an inner function
- you're brute-forcing a solution when there's more efficient ways to achieve this

An example of a working solution that fixes some of the issues, but has the same approach you chose:

```
from copy import deepcopy


def find_sums(target_sums, xs):
    def _all_sums(enumerated_xs, sums, grouping):
        if not enumerated_xs:
            yield grouping
            return

        i, v = enumerated_xs[0]
        for j in range(len(sums)):
            if sums[j] + v <= target_sums[j]:
                new_grouping = deepcopy(grouping)
                new_grouping[j] += [(i, v)]
                yield from _all_sums(enumerated_xs[1:], sums[:j] + [sums[j] + v] + sums[j+1:], new_grouping)

    if sum(target_sums) != sum(xs):
        return

    yield from _all_sums(list(enumerate(xs)), [0]*len(target_sums), [[] for _ in range(len(target_sums))])


print(list(find_sums([3, 5], [1, 3, 1, 3])))
```

Even closer, and perhaps preferable to you:

```
from copy import deepcopy


def find_sums(target_sums, xs):
    def _all_sums(enumerated_xs, sums, grouping):
        if not enumerated_xs:
            yield grouping
            return

        i, v = enumerated_xs[0]
        for j in range(len(sums)):
            if sums[j] + v <= target_sums[j]:
                new_grouping = deepcopy(grouping)
                new_grouping[j] += [(i, v)]
                new_sums = sums.copy()
                new_sums[j] += v
                yield from _all_sums(enumerated_xs[1:], new_sums, new_grouping)

    if sum(target_sums) != sum(xs):
        return

    yield from _all_sums(list(enumerate(xs)), [0]*len(target_sums), [[] for _ in range(len(target_sums))])


print(list(find_sums([3, 5], [1, 3, 1, 3])))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive response! I had to make some minor adjustments to your code to accommodate cases where certain numbers might not contribute to the resulting sublists. Your solution clarified my misunderstanding. I initially thought that the recursive function call would automatically copy the variables. This misconception stemmed from the fact that using a variable variation like sums[:j] + [sums[j] + v] + sums[j+1:] indeed creates a new variable, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, constructing a new list and assigning that value to another variable (is how I would phrase it) avoids the problem. A simple way of creating copy of a list `xs` would `xs_copy = xs[:]` - the construction in the example also replaces the value at the relevant index. Using `.copy()` achieves the same, but requires the replacement to happen after. If you feel this answers your question, consider clicking the checkmark next to it, so that your question no longer appears as unanswered.

Comment: Yes, this completely answers my question. Thank you very much!